# Understanding a step in building a product measure

Tags: integration, measure-theory

The following is from Dudley's Real analysis and probability (2nd ed.), page 134:

Let $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{C},\nu)$ be measure spaces. Let $\mathcal{R}:=\{B\times C: B\in\mathcal{B}, C\in\mathcal{C}\}$. Then $\mathcal{R}$ is a semiring. For an $R\in\mathcal{R}$ such that $R=B\times C$ define $\rho(R)=\mu(B)\nu(C)$ and $0\cdot\infty:=\infty\cdot 0:=0$.

**Theorem 4.4.1.** $\rho$ *is countably additive on* $\mathcal{R}$.

*Proof.* Suppose $B\times C=\bigcup_nB(n)\times C(n)$ in $\mathcal{R}$ where the sets $B(n)\times C(n)$ are disjoint, $B(n)\in\mathcal{B}$ and $C(n)\in\mathcal{C}$ for all $n$. So for each $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, $1_B(x)1_C(y)=\sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)1_{C(n)}(y)$. Then integrating $d\nu(y)$ gives for each $x$, by countable additivity, $1_B(x)\nu(C)=\sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)\nu(C(n))$.

**Question:** It is clear how to get the left-hand side of the last equation. How does one verify that $\int \sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)1_{C(n)}(y)d\nu(y)=\sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)\nu(C(n))$? I suppose countable additivity of $\nu$ is meant, but I think that $B(n)\times C(n)$ being disjoint for all $n$ does not imply $C(n)$ being disjoint for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the sets $(C(n))_{n\geqslant 1}$ may be not disjoint. However, defining for a fixed $x$,
$$f_N(y):=\sum_{n=1}^N\chi_{B(n)}(x)\chi_{C(n)}(y),$$
and $n(y)$ as the *unique* integer $n$ such that $\chi_{B(n)}(x)\chi_{C(n)}(y)=1$ if $(x,y)\in B\times C$, we have by monotone convergence 
$$\int \sum_n\chi_{B(n)}(x)\chi_{C(n)}(y)\mathrm d\nu(y)=\lim_{N\to \infty}\int f_N(y)\mathrm d\nu(y)=\sum_n\chi_{B(n)}(x)\int\chi_{C(n)}(y)\mathrm d\nu(y).$$

Alternatively, we can use countably additivity of $\nu$, we first have to break the $C(n)$ and $B(n)$ into pairwise disjoint sets (define $B'_k:=B_k\setminus \bigcup_{j\lt k}B(j)$, similarly for $C_k$).

Comment: $\int \chi_{C(n)}(y)d\nu(y)=\nu(C(n))$ so to show $\int \sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)1_{C(n)}(y)d\nu(y)=\sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)\nu(C(n))$  you used monotone convergence, but the original proof mentions countable additivity, and I don't see how it applies. What do you use your $I_k$ for?

Comment: Actually the $I_k$ are not needed, I removed it.

Comment: So, I guess what you're saying is we can assume $B(n)$ and $C(n)$ to be disjoint. I still don't see how to use countable additivity to calculate $\int \sum_n1_{B(n)}(x)1_{C(n)}(y)d\nu(y)$.